# Android wear: geofence - ApiException: 1000

Tags: android, gps, wear-os, android-geofence

I am building an Android app for **Android Wear**. For battery savings I am trying to use Geofences to track if you enter or exit a location. But I cannot get it working.

**First of all I am not sure if Geofences are supported on Android Wear? (Standalone?)** I have a Huawei watch 2 LTE which contains a GPS antenne, and **I already got the FusedLocationClient working so I know the GPS works.** I also got my geofencing code working on the phone with no problems.

**When I run the code I get the following exception:**

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 1000:
```

I found on the [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofenceStatusCodes) that this means:   `GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE` which gives me no extra info.

This is the service I wrote to start and create the geofence:

```
public class GeofencingService extends Service implements OnSuccessListener, OnFailureListener {

    private static final String TAG = "GeofencingService";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient;
    private List<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
        createGeofences();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        showNofification();
        setupGeofence();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();

        // The INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER flag indicates that geofencing service should trigger a
        // GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER notification when the geofence is added and if the device
        // is already inside that geofence.
        builder.setInitialTrigger(INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT);

        // Add the geofences to be monitored by geofencing service.
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);

        // Return a GeofencingRequest.
        return builder.build();
    }

    private void setupGeofence()
    {
        try{
            Log.i(TAG, "Setting up geofences...");
            mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent()).addOnSuccessListener(this).addOnFailureListener(this);
        } catch (SecurityException ex)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void createGeofences()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating geofence...");
        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId("Test1")
                // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                .setCircularRegion(
                        50.03535,
                        4.33139,
                        100
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(NEVER_EXPIRE)
                // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                .setTransitionTypes(GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                // Create the geofence.
                .build());
    }

    private void showNofification()
    {
        Intent appIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, appIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.location_service_title))
                .setContentText(getText(R.string.location_service_text))
                .setLocalOnly(true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .build();

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setupGeofence();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object o) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Success!");
    }
}
```

[Here is also a github link to the example I wrote.](https://github.com/kevingoos/WearableGeofenceTests)

Hopefully somebody can help me figure this out, because I already tried everything I know :)

Comment: What does 1000 mean?

Comment: @greenapps As I found on this website: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofenceStatusCodes
it means: GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Comment: Ok. Then please comment.

Comment: @greenapps That is just the exception. No solution?

Comment: That is not a comment. You should comment on the message that geofence is not available. What do you conclude?

Comment: You may want to check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37579418/5995040), "Not all wear devices have the hardware to support this, though the LG urbane 2 has LTE and quite a few Wear devices support wifi." It should be pair with a handheld in order to use Geofencing as stated in the SO post. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot My watch (Huawei Watch 2 LTE) has a GPS, LTE, Wifi, ... It is connected to a phone, but that doesn't help.

Comment: @kevingoos any updates on this? I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you read the documentation and see that the error code is corresponding to  `GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE`, plus according to @Mr.Rebot comment :

> "Not all wear devices have the hardware to support this [...]"

You may assume that **GEOFENCE IS NOT AVAILABLE** on your Huawei watch 2 device.

You may also ask [to Huawei support](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/) directly to have confirmation.

Comment: huawei support is really awful

Answer (score 0):

This error also comes when location is not turned on. You need to enable location to let geofence work.